# Javascript group elements with identical classnames

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodelist

I want to select all elements with class name `find-me` and group them in separate arrays (or NodeLists) based on their other classes, if idential. Here is an example:

```html
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 1
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 2
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 3
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 4
</div>
<div class="find-me one two four">
  Element 5
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 6
</div>
<div class="one two">
  Element 7
</div>
```

My goal is to have:

- One array or NodeList with elements 1, 2 and 6 (`find-me, one, two`)
- One array or NodeList with elements 3 and 4 (`find-me, one, two, three`)
- One array or NodeList with element 5 (`find-me, one, two, four`)
- Element 7 should not be taken into account since it doesn't have the `find-me` class

I suppose I have to use `document.querySelectorAll('.find-me')` to first get a NodeList of all the elements I am interested in.

But then? I was thinking I could compare the list of classes from the current element with the previous one but how can I keep track of what element goes to what group? Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Instead of writing something custom, why not just use querySelectors with exactly those selectors? Like `.find-me.one.two:not(.three)`? If you are going to be sorting anyway you might as well just take the time to write those queries? And if you need something more abstract, consider just creating the queries and let the browser handle the rest?

Comment: Because I don't know the other classNames in advance. All I know is that all the elements I am interested in will have the `find-me` class. Then, as explained in my question, I need to group them by identical classes. I do **not** know what classes they have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a good opportunity to use [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy), but be aware of its [poor coverage](https://caniuse.com/?search=object.groupby)

```js
const groups = Object.groupBy(document.querySelectorAll('.find-me'), e => e.classList);

console.log(groups);
```

```html
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 1
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 2
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 3
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 4
</div>
<div class="find-me one two four">
  Element 5
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 6
</div>
<div class="one two">
  Element 7
</div>
```

Using the same concept, you can write a reduce function to achieve the same goal, also the order/repetitive classes doesn't matter:

```js
const groups = [...document.querySelectorAll('.find-me')].reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const key = [...cur.classList].sort();
  acc[key] ??= [];
  // use the following code instead of the line above if you need to support IE11
  // acc[key] || (acc[key] = []);
  acc[key].push(cur);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

```html
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 1
</div>
<div class="two find-me one one">
  Element 2
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 3
</div>
<div class="find-me one three two ">
  Element 4
</div>
<div class="find-me one two four">
  Element 5
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 6
</div>
<div class="one two">
  Element 7
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. Indeed, coverage is not great so I might not use it since it's for a public website. Also note that changing the order of classnames will create additional arrays (but I didn't mention that in my question).

Comment: I've updated the answer and provided a solution with better compatibility based on the same concept. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```js
const findMeElements = document.querySelectorAll('.find-me');

const groupedElements = {};

findMeElements.forEach(element => {
    const currentClasses = Array.from(element.classList);

    const otherClasses = currentClasses.filter(className => className !== 'find-me');

    otherClasses.sort();

    const key = otherClasses.join(',');

    if (groupedElements[key]) {
        groupedElements[key].push(element);
    } else {
        groupedElements[key] = [element];
    }
});

console.log(groupedElements);
```

```html
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 1
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 2
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 3
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 4
</div>
<div class="find-me one two four">
  Element 5
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 6
</div>
<div class="one two">
  Element 7
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through each element in the NodeList then for each element, extract its classList and convert it into a string so you can use it as a key in an object. If an array already exists for that particular combination of classes, push the element into that array. If not, create a new array (or NodeList) and add the element to it.

**Demo**:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.find-me');
const groupedElements = {};

elements.forEach(element => {
  const classList = Array.from(element.classList).sort().join(' ');
  if (groupedElements[classList]) {
    groupedElements[classList].push(element);
  } else {
    groupedElements[classList] = [element];
  }
});

// Logging the grouped elements in a more readable format
for (const classes in groupedElements) {
  const elements = groupedElements[classes];
  console.log(`Elements with classes "${classes}":`);
  elements.forEach((element, index) => {
    console.log(`  Element ${index + 1}: ${element.textContent.trim()}`);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 1
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 2
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 3
</div>
<div class="find-me one two three">
  Element 4
</div>
<div class="find-me one two four">
  Element 5
</div>
<div class="find-me one two">
  Element 6
</div>
<div class="one two">
  Element 7
</div>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorting the class names before joining them is a good practice to ensure consistency.